# TFLite Change Parameters of HardSigmoid

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a neural network that uses the [Hard Sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/hard_sigmoid) activation function.

However, the keras version of the activation function isn't used, instead it's computed like this:

```
def hard_sigmoid(x):
    return layers.ReLU(6.)(x + 3.) * (1. / 6.)
```

This means that the parameter `alpha` should be set to `0.1667` rather than the default value of `0.2` specified in the link above.

It seems that when the TFLite conversion process is run the name hard_sigmoid is recognized as the keras function. This means my model outputs nonsense.

The same process for coreML conversion allows me to directly edit the underlying model protobuf file to specify the correct value for alpha.

Is there a good way to solve this for TFLite?

Comment: Your example is a `hard_swish` function, according to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336568/hard-swish-for-tflite

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `keras.backend`

```
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.backend as K


def myCustomActivation(x):
    return ...

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Activation(myCustomActivation))

model.add(Dense(30, activation= myCustomActivation))

...
```

for all operations performed in your `myCustomActivation` use the Keras backend to get operations executed on the DAG.